# Shipyard deploy error. It Don't map docker socket

Tags: centos, docker

I have installed Centos 7 and docker (Server version: 0.11.1-dev).
I'm following the quickstart of [Shipyard](https://github.com/shipyard/shipyard/wiki/QuickStart).

I pulled the docker image shipyard/deploy:

> docker pull shipyard/deploy

When I run the command:

> docker run -i -t -v /var/run/docker.sock:/docker.sock shipyard/deploy setup

I get the next error:

> You must map your Docker socket to /docker.sock (i.e. -v /var/run/docker.sock:/docker.sock)

I check the file docker.sock:

> ls -la /var/run/docker.sock
>
> srw-rw----. 1 root docker 0 sep 11 07:24 /var/run/docker.sock

Selinux check

> ls -Z /var/run/docker.sock
>
> srw-rw----. root docker system_u:object_r:docker_var_run_t:s0 /var/run/docker.sock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience with Docker, SELinux, and CentOS, I'm unable to map volumes unless the SELinux context is `unconfined_u:object_r:svirt_sandbox_file_t:s0`.

Maybe you should try:

```
chcon -Rt svirt_sandbox_file_t /var/run/docker.sock
```

(YMMV. I don't know if this will wreck something else!)

Comment: In current versions of Docker you can [use the z or Z docker volume mount options](http://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2015/06/using-volumes-with-docker-can-cause-problems-with-selinux/) (capital Z being preferred).